# Issues replacing backslashes in paths

Tags: regex, sed, command-line, backslash, babun

I am trying to replace backslashes in Windows paths so that I can paste the path in Filezilla to open the folder without having to browser in the directory structure. I use the following command:

```
echo '\path\to\the\05_directory' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g'
```

My expected result is

```
/path/to/the/05_directory
```

but instead I get

```
/path   o       he_directory
```

it seems `\t` and `\05` are interpreted as something other than literal strings.

Why does this happen? How can I work this around?

Comment: What are you using? In linux command line `echo '\path\to\the\05_directory' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g'` output `/path/to/the/05_directory`

Comment: Are you sure it is `echo` and not `echo -e`?

Comment: As an aside, for a single character, instead of using sed, you can use tr: `tr '\\' '/'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add: I am using babun (a command-line emulator similar to cygwin) under Windows. Using `tr '\\' '/'` gives the same result.

Comment: @msoutopico, can you try the sed command with file input instead of echo? for ex: `sed -e 's/\\/\//g' file.txt` where file.txt contains `\path\to\the\05_directory`

Comment: Sundeep, your suggestion works as long as I open file.txt in a text editor (nano, vim, sublime, etc.) and paste the old path there. However, I was looking for something quicker. If I do `echo "\path\to\the\05_directory" > file.txt` then I get the same buggy result that I had reported. If I have to paste the path in a text editor, it's just easier to do the replacement there rather than in the command line. Thanks anyway. It seems this is a bug with `echo` in babun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf "%q"` to print the literal `\` vs having them interpreted as tabs:

```
printf "%q" '\path\to\the\05_directory' 
\\path\\to\\the\\05_directory
```

Then you can use `sed` to get your output:

```
printf "%q" '\path\to\the\05_directory' | sed -e 's|\\\\|/|g'
/path/to/the/05_directory
```

The `"%q"` field prepares a string to be used in the shell. That of course means that `' '` will be escaped:

```
printf "%q" '\path\to\the\05 directory' 
\\path\\to\\the\\05\ directory
```

Which you can clean up separately:

```
printf "%q" '\path\to\the\05 directory' | sed -e 's|\\\\|/|g; s|\\||g'
/path/to/the/05 directory
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't use babun anymore I can't test your solution. Now I use WSL's terminal and I can't reproduce the issue, my initial approach works as expected. Since your suggestion works on WSL and seems helpful, I will accept your answer (knowing that I don't know whether it actually fixes the original issue in the environment I was using at the time -- 3 years ago)